# Decoding JSON Data from PHP Page Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I want to take data from database and save it in an array.
Like this

```
 var locations = [ ['Current', 18.53515053, 73.87944794, 2],

  ['VimanNagar', 18.5670762, 73.9084194, 1]
];
```

First of all I have created a php page

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "citytrans";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM driver_location";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo json_encode($row);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

which gives me below result

```
{"driver_id":"1","driver_lat":"18.53515053","driver_lng":"73.87944794","driver_code":"122"}{"driver_id":"2","driver_lat":"18.53640175","driver_lng":"73.88206482","driver_code":"133"}
```

Now I want to convert this into an array using Jquery (I want to decode it ), I just want `drivers_lat` and `drivers_lng` value from my jSON data fetched form the database show above.

I am using below code to parse the data form json

```
jQuery.ajax({                              
    url: baseurl +  "getdriverlocation.php",
    type: "JSON",
    async: false,
    success: function(data){
           var myArray = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(myArray.driver_lat)
    } 
});
```

but it is giving me error (shown below)

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after
>   JSON data at line 1 column 92 of the JSON data

I just want the two values from json data and save it in an array variable

Please help

Comment: the proplem is, that you are concatenating several json-objects to _one_ string, which results in a non valid json. (in your while-loop)

Comment: echo json_encode($row); is in a while loop. So the string returned is not proper

Comment: There is no such type `JSON`, i think you missed `dataType`?

Comment: solution would be to first store all the result in _one_ array, then json_encode that one array and echo that.

Comment: Use array..Push in array...and echo it by end of your php script...

Comment: Is my jquery code is correct?

Comment: @AnkitSharma _Is my jquery code is correct?_ NO!, as far as you have wrong type and async set to false.

Comment: @Jai, Will `async:false` cause  any harm ? And `dataType` is not needed if you are pasring JSON manually..

Comment: @RayonDabre you know it sir! but OP doesn't. agreed with second part.

Comment: @Jai, yes..But it does not make it invalid..Just a _BAD PRACTICE_.. By the way, `sir` did sound like a BAD WORD ;(

Comment: @RayonDabre hmmm....got your point. may be i should have added more  in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one..

```
jQuery.ajax({                              
url: baseurl +  "getdriverlocation.php",
type: "JSON",
async: false,
success: function(data){
       var myArray = jQuery.parseJSON(data);// instead of JSON.parse(data)
       jQuery(myArray).each(function( index, element ) {     
         console.log(element.driver_lat)
       });
} 
});
```

Comment: Please provide me the complete output from getdriverlocation.php page

Comment: [{"driver_id":"2","driver_lat":"18.53640175","driver_lng":"73.88206482","driver_code":"133"}]

Comment: earlier i am gettinh this output {"driver_id":"1","driver_lat":"18.53515053","driver_lng":"73.87944794","driver_code":"122"}, {"driver_id":"2","driver_lat":"18.53640175","driver_lng":"73.88206482","driver_code":"133"} but after using your code i am getting 
 
[{"driver_id":"2","driver_lat":"18.53640175","driver_lng":"73.88206482","driver_‌​code":"133"}] only one

Comment: given in the question

Comment: It Works ! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your php you should do :

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row <- no, build your data, then make only 1 output
    $output = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       $output[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Then in your jQuery, parse the whole json-decoded array...

Comment: what is the resulting json object your PHP sends to jQuery ?

Comment: [{"driver_id":"2","driver_lat":"18.53640175","driver_lng":"73.88206482","driver_code":"133"}]

Answer (score 1):

Your json data is invalid. 
You must put comma bettween two JSON Objects 
Your respons must be 
    {"driver_id":"1","driver_lat":"18.53515053","driver_lng":"73.87944794","driver_code":"122"}**,**
    {"driver_id":"2","driver_lat":"18.53640175","driver_lng":"73.88206482","driver_code":"133"}

Comment: this is also invalid

Answer (score 0):

As i identified your Response JSON format is invalid, response JSON format should like this in order to parse into JSON via JSON.parse()

```
    [{"driver_id":"1","driver_lat":"18.53515053","driver_lng":"73.87944794","driver_code":"122"},
{"driver_id":"2","driver_lat":"18.53640175","driver_lng":"73.88206482","driver_code":"133"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$arrTmp = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $arrTmp[] = $row;
   }
}
echo json_encode($arrTmp);
```

And maybe the jQuery tools bellow for old browsers

```
$.parseJSON(data);
```